# Is there a way to get OneNote timestamps through the OneNote API?

Tags: c#, python, timestamp, export, onenote

Is there a way to get the timestamps for content in a OneNote page through the OneNote API, or another way? I have been using the API to get the html content and metadata of my pages, however I have not found a way to get the timestamps. I want to get these so I can see an edit history. These exist in OneNote as they show up when you highlight text and right click on it, as shown: [OneNote Timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbXqm.png). Basically is there anyway to export this information? Ideally this would be in Python, but I'm not picky.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For desk-top version of OneNote, you can get the XML structure of each page. And in the XML structure, the last modfied time of each paragraph is recorded. Yes, for every paragraph.